# Dynamically select all data when creating a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have created a VBA macro to create a pivot table on the fly. The source data changes everyday, so there are different number of records each day. In the macro the number of records to select is hard coded. Is there a way to select all the data in the source table each day - instead of a predefined number of records

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Call DeleteAllPivotTablesInWorkbook
Sheets("ALL").Select
If CheckSheet("AllSummary") Then
    Sheets("AllSummary").Delete
End If
Sheets.Add.Name = "AllSummary"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets("AllSummary").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "All!R1C1:R26885C47", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="AllSummary!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion10
Sheets("AllSummary").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
```

As you can see the sourcdata value is hard coded. How can I select all the data regardless of the number of records?

Comment: Use a named range or data table?

Comment: See my edit. Just run that macro.

Comment: Or just use Dick's macro to update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "All!" & Sheets("All").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="AllSummary!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you keep your data on a separate sheet than your pivot table destination you can just use a last row/column/cell type selection to select all the relevant data on your data sheet:

```
Sub Excel2010Syntax()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R16C4", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet2!R20C1", TableName:="PivotTable4", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

This was recorded in excel 2010 ( I think you have an earlier version ) but you get the idea. Just have a dedicated data sheet and then select all the data on it to create your pivot table.

**EDIT:**

Or just run this macro:

```
Sub Answer()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("All")
Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
Sheets("AllSummary").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "All!R1C1:R" & CStr(rng1.Row) & "C" & CStr(rng1.Column), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="AllSummary!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion10
Sheets("AllSummary").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: simply selecting the data will not affect what is used as the data source for the pivot-your code still has a hard-coded range

Comment: @JosieP Yea, It was a concept description. He would have to concatenate the address of the last cell into the SourceData string field. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider if you should be recreating the pivot table. If you just want to change where the pivot table points to, you can do that without deleting and creating it.

This sub finds the first pivot table on the AllSummary sheet and changes its PivotCache's SourceData property. The SourceData property is changed using the CurrentRegion property of the range object. When you're dealing with pivot tables, you usually have pretty well structured data and if that's the case, CurrentRegion will return the range that includes any new rows or columns added.

The Address property uses R1C1 because that's what SourceData expects and also uses True in the External argument to get the sheet's name in the address.

```
Sub AdjustPtSource()

    Dim pt As PivotTable

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set pt = .Worksheets("AllSummary").PivotTables(1)
        pt.PivotCache.SourceData = .Worksheets("All").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlR1C1, True)
    End With

End Sub
```

If you must delete and recreate, you can still use CurrentRegion to get the whole contiguous range.

```
Sub MakePT()

    Dim shSum As Worksheet
    Dim shAll As Worksheet
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Const sWSSUMMARY As String = "AllSummary"

    DeleteAllPivotTablesInWorkbook
    Set shAll = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All")

    If CheckSheet(sWSSUMMARY) Then
        Sheets(sWSSUMMARY).Delete
    End If

    Set shSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    shSum.Name = sWSSUMMARY

    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, shAll.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(shSum.Cells(3, 1))

End Sub
```